# javaScriptEscape not working inside javascript file (Spring-MVC)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying got use spring-mvc tag inside java-script file, here is what i am trying to do

```
var firstName="<spring:theme code='register.firstName.invalid' javaScriptEscape='true'> ";
```

seems like its not working as when using `alert(firstName)` its giving the same text and not the text from resource bundle.

Is there something i am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it just a static js file or a javascript inside JSP?

Comment: its static js file being includes in the header section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard javascript file aren't processed by Spring, it's just a static file, that served by web container as-is, w/o any transformation.

If you need to setup some Javascript variabled using server side logic (like Spring tags), you can do it inside JSP, and the use it from javascript.

Or also you can write your own request filter, that will process and transform your static files on the fly, but it's major performance loss.

Comment: i was thinking same on creating a filter.Thanks for the input :)